# More help with json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm still trying to get the grasp of using JSON with php and jquery.

I have a page which queries a database to get all users who have upcoming birthdays (ignore the sql, its just for this example)  The code grabs the database return and puts it into an array, which looks something like this:

```
Array (
 [idnum] => Array (
   [0] => 3
   [1] => 10
   [2] => 74
 )
 [name] => Array (
   [0] => Betty Smith
   [1] => Jim Pierce
   [2] => Sam Smith
 )
)
```

I want to put this data into some jquery to display to the user in an html select statement or something similar, so that they can make a choice, and then retain an IDnum for future code/ajax.

My code follows, in its entirety:

```
<?php
session_start();

$sql_server = 'xxxx';
$sql_db = 'xxxx';
$sql_username = 'xxxx';
$sql_password = 'xxxx';

$db = mysql_connect("$sql_server", "$sql_username", "$sql_password") or die ("Error connecting to database.");
mysql_select_db("$sql_db", $db) or die ("Couldn't select the database.");

list($currentdate) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT currentdate FROM calendar",$db));

/////////////////////////


$result = mysql_query("SELECT IDvalue, name FROM people where birthday => $currentdate",$db);
$rowcheck = mysql_num_rows($result);
//echo $rowcheck;
$birthdays = array();
$i = '0';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach ($row as $col => $val){
        if ($col == 'IDvalue') {
         //print " $val ";
         $birthdays['idnum'][$i] = $val;
         }
         if ($col == 'name') {
            $birthdays['name'][$i] = $val; 
         }

    }
    $i++;

   }


echo "</br></br><input type=\"button\" id=\"showbirthdays\" value=\"Show birthdays\"/>";
?>  
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body>

<script src="jquery.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    $('#showbirthdays').click(function() {

        var jsonobj = <?php echo json_encode($birthdays); ?>;
        //alert (jsonobj) //  this does not seem to work.  just gives [object Object]

        // Here's where i'm really lost.  I would like to use jquery to display
        // a select box that shows the name of birthday people, and uses their IDnum as an identifer for further code.
        // some kind of foreach with an html.push, and then append to a div on the page...?


        });
    </script>

    </body>


</html>


}
?>
```

I would very much like to see exactly how to grab that array data within the jquery, and use it.  Or, if someone has a suggestion of a different way to move the data, I'm interested in alternatives.

**Edit:**

```
$.each(jsonobj, function(){
            //Here `this` will point to each element of the object
            alert (this);
        });
```

Works great, gives me output like this: "Betty Smith,Jim Pierce, Sam Smith".

```
$.each(jsonobj.name, function(){
```

This also works, and gives me separate output with the names,

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
var html = [];
html.push('<select name="birthdaynames" id="birthdayselect">')
$.each(jsonobj, function(){
      html.push('<option name="asdf" id="this.IDnum">' + this.name + '</option>')      

        });
html.push('</select>')
$('#showbirthdays').append(html.join(''));
```

**How do I get those specific values using (this)?**

Comment: Not an answer but a hint: Using variables in quotes (e.g. "$var") is considered very bad style.

Comment: jsonobj is an actual js object, so the alert is correct. try `alert(jsonobj.name[0])` and you'll see the first name

Comment: @jeremy: When you do `$.each(jsonobj, function(){`, `this` is each array (idnum, then name), what you need to do is `$.each` over each array.  Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object Object]` is correct, when you are trying to alert a JavaScript object.

Try to `alert(jsonobj.idnum)` or `alert(jsonobj.name)`.

To make a `<select>` you can use `$.each` to loop through the data.

```
var $sel = $('<select name="birthdaynames" id="birthdayselect">');
$.each(jsonobj.idnum, function(i,v){
    var name = jsonobj.name[i];
    var $opt = $('<option/>').val(v).text(name);
    $sel.append($opt);
});
$('#showbirthdays').append($sel);
```

Comment: that would return [array Array]

Comment: @Einacio: No it wouldn't.  Alerting arrays prints the values separated by commas.

Comment: You're right, sorry. i was working with another language and mixed it up

Answer (score 3):

If `<?php echo json_encode($birthdays); ?>` writes a well form js array or object then you can direct use it as

```
var jsonobj = <?php echo json_encode($birthdays); ?>;
```

`alert` jsonobj is giving you `[[object Object]` because it is a javascript object. You can try to alert `jsonobj.length` if it is an array.

You can loop through this object using `$.each` loop.

```
var html = [];
html.push('<select name="birthdaynames" id="birthdayselect">')
$.each(jsonobj, function(){
     html.push('<option value="'+this.IDvalue + '">' + this.name + '</option>')      
});
html.push('</select>')
$('#showbirthdays').append(html.join(''));
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks.  Since my array is multidimensional, I see that alert(this) gives me an alert with all the names, and then an alert with all the IDnums.  How can I more effectively handle that to create an html select?  I'm modifying the question above to reflect.

Comment: @jeremy - Take a look at my edited answer. I believe you have `IDnum` property for each element. If not then replace it accordingly with proper name. Also for `option` element you don't need a `name` attribue and `id`(only if you want to select by id)

Comment: This creates the select, but the options show up as 
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>

Comment: In my previous comment I mention it. Do you have `IDnum` property in the object.  If not then replace it accordingly with proper name it will work fine. I think it is `IDvalue`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
jsonobj.your_array_key;
```

to access the json object data into javascript.
If you have any array then just do jquery each with it.